# Guiding a "build" through the development, build, and deploy process

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, slowcheetah

## Problem

Using TFS--specifically Team Build--I am trying to come up with a strategy for building and deploying several web applications. I'm struggling with defining how exactly I want to perform those builds and deployments.

In this case, I define builds as what one creates when one compiles any application. I define a deployment as what one actually releases to some environment, even if that environment is internal.

TFS provides one with a way to create a Build. The generated Build's quality may be set by appropriate users. A Build may have a quality of Ready for Testing, Passed in QA, Passed in UAT, Failed, Released, etc.

## Possibilities

I have worked on projects that have build definitions set up in TFS that correspond to deployments. So, for example, a PC will have the Builds ReleaseQA, ReleaseUAT, and ReleaseProd. Although this definitely works and is integrated into TFS, it feels like cheating to me; rather than creating one build and shepherding it through one's environments, one is creating many builds and deploying each to a different environment.

I envision a process that works by **generating** a Build and then **promoting** that Build through the various environments.

**Awesome**

Right-click a particular completed build in TFS and pick Deploy->UAT.

**Less Awesome**

A folder of scripts sitting on my build machine with titles like deploy-build-qa, deploy-build-uat, and deploy-build-prod; one calls them with a build number and the script deploys that build to the appropriate environment

## You

Is there a well integrated way to do something like the Awesome scenario I propose or am I stuck with something less awesome? If there isn't anything "out of the box", I am open to add-ons or applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible! I've been implementing it today for the infrastructure of a new project I'm working on :)

I came to use [TfsDeployer](http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/).

First I crated a powershell script that uses [MSDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy) (we're building a solution with multiple Web and WCF projects) and then link the scripts to TfsDeployer.

Now I can change the quality of a build and kick of a powershell script that will deploy the build to a test, acceptance or production server.

Something I also really liked for helping with all the config transformations is [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5). It helps with defining transformations for all xml files and the ability to simply preview the transformation.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 for SlowCheetah. I hadn't heard of it, and it will be great when I'm playing around with more esoteric transforms.